# TweetDeck like UI in Java

Tags: java, swing

Can anyone guide me how can I create GUI like TweetDeck in Java(Desktop programming). Using Java swing packages, I get simple looks. How can I make it more eye catchy? :)

Answer (score 1):

The UI look and feel (L&F) in TweetDeck can be applied in your Java desktop program by using Nimrod L&F. You can try it at http://personales.ya.com/nimrod/screenshots-en.html. For the grayish theme, you can save the .theme file below:

```
nimrodlf.p1=#A1A0A0
nimrodlf.p2=#ABAAAA
nimrodlf.p3=#B5B4B4
nimrodlf.s1=#464746
nimrodlf.s2=#666666
nimrodlf.s3=#5A5B5A
nimrodlf.w=#717171
nimrodlf.b=#FFFFFF
nimrodlf.menuOpacity=140
nimrodlf.frameOpacity=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the look and feel of your applications in order to get some eye catching looks. Take a look at [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) tutorial to know how to set look and feel in java. [This](http://geeknizer.com/best-java-swing-look-and-feel-themes-professional-casual-top-10/) link will introduce you with some nice look and feels. All of those look and feels are not provided to you by default. So you have to download those jars, add it to your project path and then you will be able to use it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Make your own custom components that look exactly like you want them too.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Filthy rich clients. Chet Haase and Romain Guy was legendary for creating stunning UI's in Java. This is still the first book I look at when I need to jazz up a UI a bit.

http://filthyrichclients.org/